# While statement is checking but allowing invalid inputs

Tags: java, math, while-loop, geometry, error-checking

I'm am trying to write a program that reads in 3 numbers as the lengths of sides of a triangle. These numbers must represent a possible triangle and if 3 zeros are entered it will terminate the program. I have it working sort of. It terminates of 3 zeros are entered at the start but not after, even though I'm pretty sure I have a while checking for that. Also in the provided pictures those values should not work.

```
 *Program Description:
 *This program reads an arbitrary number of sets of triangle sides using only integer values. The progam will: 
 *Prompt the user for sets of numbers and process them until the user submits the numbers 0 0 0, which will terminate the program. 
 *For each set of three numbers, the program will print the values read. 
 *For each set of three numbers, the program will decide if the numbers represent the sides of a valid triangle. 
 *If the numbers can not represent a valid triangle, it will display an appropriate error message. 
 *If the numbers are valid, the program will determine, and display, the: 
 *side classification of the triangle – equilateral, isosceles, or scalene 
 *angle classification of the triangle – right, acute, or obtuse*/
import java.util.Scanner;
class triangleType
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    int side1 = -6, side2 = -1, side3 = -1; 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter three integers that represent VALID sides of a triangle. Enter 0 0 0 to terminate the program.");
    side1 = in.nextInt();
    side2 = in.nextInt();
    side3 = in.nextInt();
    while (side1!=0&&side2!=0&&side3!=0)//checks if the user entered 3 zeros to skip the loop and terminate the program
    {
      while ((side1<=0||side2<=0||side3<=0))
      {
        System.out.println("You have entered at least one invalid value. This means your values could not make a triangle. Please enter new values.");
        side1 = in.nextInt();
        side2 = in.nextInt();
  side3 = in.nextInt();
      }
      while ((side1>=side2+side3||side2>=side1+side3||side3>=side2+side1))//checks if side values entered by user are valid
      {
        System.out.println("You have entered at least one invalid value. This means your values could not make a triangle. Please enter new values.");
        side1 = in.nextInt();
        side2 = in.nextInt();
        side3 = in.nextInt();
        if (side1==0&&side2==0&&side3==0)//checks if the user entered 3 zeros to break the loop and terminate the program
        {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (side1==0&&side2==0&&side3==0)//checks if the user entered 3 zeros to terminate the program, if not the program will run
    {
      System.out.println("You have chosen to terminate the program.");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("Your side lengths are valid. You entered: " + side1 + ", " + side2 + " and " + side3);
      if((isIsosceles (side1, side2, side3)) == true)
      {
        System.out.println("Side classification of the triangle: Isosceles"); 
      }
      else if((isEquilateral (side1, side2, side3)) == true)
      {
        System.out.println("Side classification of the triangle: Equilateral");
      }
      else
      {
System.out.println("Side classification of the triangle: Scalene");
      }
      if ((isAcute (side1, side2, side3)) == true)
      {
        System.out.println("Angle classification of the triangle: Acute");
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("Angle classification of the triangle: Obtuse");
      }
    }
  }

  public static boolean isEquilateral (int s1, int s2, int s3)/*takes inputs: side 1, 2 and 3 as integers. Checks to see if this triangle is equilateral
   Returns boolean result of whether or not the triangle is equilateral.*/
  {
    if ((s1==s2)&&(s2==s3))//checks to see if all sides are equal, if so it will run and return true if not it will return false
    {
      return true;
    }
    else 
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public static boolean isIsosceles (int s1, int s2, int s3)/*takes inputs: side 1, 2 and 3 as integers. Checks to see if this triangle is isosceles
   Returns boolean result of whether or not the triangle is isosceles.*/
  {
    if (((s1==s2)&&s1!=s3)||((s1==s3)&&s1!=s2)||((s2==s3)&&s2!=s1))//checks to see if two sides are equal, if so it will run and return true if not it will return false
    {
  return true;
    }
    else 
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  public static boolean isScalene (int s1, int s2, int s3)/*takes inputs: side 1, 2 and 3 as integers. Checks to see if this triangle is scalene
   Returns boolean result of whether or not the triangle is scalene.*/
  {
    if ((s1!=s2)&&(s1!=s3)&&(s2!=s3))//checks to see if all sides are not equal, if so it will run and return true if not it will return false
    {
      return true;
    }
    else 
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public static boolean isAcute (int s1, int s2, int s3)/*takes inputs: side 1, 2 and 3 as integers. Checks to see if this triangle is acute
   Returns boolean result of whether or not the triangle is acute.*/
  {
    int sqrOne = 0, sqrTwo = 0;
    if (s1<s3&&s2<s3)//checks to see if the lengths of side 1 and 2 are less than side 3
    {
      sqrOne = (s1*s1)+(s2*s2);
      sqrTwo = s3*s3;
 if (sqrOne>sqrTwo)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else 
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (s1<s2&&s3<s2)//checks to see if the lengths of side 1 and 3 are less than side 2
    {
      sqrOne = (s1*s1)+(s3*s3);
      sqrTwo = s2*s2;
      if (sqrOne>sqrTwo)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else 
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (s2<s1&&s3<s1)//checks to see if the lengths of side 2 and 3 are less than side 1`
    {
      sqrOne = (s2*s2)+(s3*s3);
      sqrTwo = s1*s1;
      if (sqrOne>sqrTwo)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else 
{
        return false;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  public static boolean isObtuse (int s1, int s2, int s3)/*takes inputs: side 1, 2 and 3 as integers. Checks to see if this triangle is obtuse
   Returns boolean result of whether or not the triangle is obtuse.*/
  {
    int sqrOne = 0, sqrTwo = 0;
    if (s1<s3&&s2<s3)//checks to see if the lengths of side 1 and 2 are less than side 3
    {
      sqrOne = (s1*s1)+(s2*s2);
      sqrTwo = s3*s3;
      if (sqrOne<sqrTwo)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else 
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (s1<s2&&s3<s2)//checks to see if the lengths of side 1 and 3 are less than side 2
    {
      sqrOne = (s1*s1)+(s3*s3);
      sqrTwo = s2*s2;
      if (sqrOne<sqrTwo)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else 
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (s2<s1&&s3<s1)//checks to see if the lengths of side 2 and 3 are less than side 1
    {
      sqrOne = (s2*s2)+(s3*s3);
      sqrTwo = s1*s1;
      if (sqrOne<sqrTwo)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else 
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please state your problem exactly! I don't understand what you are asking. Also be aware that questions "asking for debugging help" need to include a "minimal complete verifiable example" (aka. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) to be on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It terminates of 3 zeros are entered at the start but not after,

After your first valid input, you aren't getting new values.

A do-while is frequently valuable when you want to ask at least once.

```
do {
   side1 = in.nextInt();
   side2 = in.nextInt();
   side3 = in.nextInt();

   if ( side1!=0 || side2!=0 || side3!=0 ) {
      ...
   }
}
while (side1!=0 || side2!=0 || side3!=0);
```

Also, note that you don't need nested loops for invalid data. If the data is invalid, you could just print a message and go on to the next iteration of the outer loop.

**EDIT:** As suggested by the paragraph above:

```
do {
   side1 = in.nextInt();
   side2 = in.nextInt();
   side3 = in.nextInt();

   if ( side1!=0 || side2!=0 || side3!=0 ) {
       if ( side1<=0 || side2<=0 || side3<=0 ) {
          System.out.println("Triangle sides must be positive values.\nPlease enter new values.");
       }
       else if ( side1>=side2+side3 || side2>=side1+side3 || side3>=side2+side1 ) {
          System.out.println("Those sides cannot form a triangle.\nPlease enter new values.");
       }
       else {
           // ... Classify the triangle. 
       }
   }
}
while (side1!=0 || side2!=0 || side3!=0);
```

Comment: but if you enter 1 or more invalid ones, it asks again and does not terminate after 3 zeros are entered

Comment: You have additional inputs until you get a valid one. Having one set of input statements at the top of the loop would make this much easier.

Comment: could you have a look at my comment on ZakDaniels answer, your reputation looks like you may be able to help ;)

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69 - Check the additional code above. A good first step is to lay out the problem in English comments. A subsequent step is to run the code in a debugger, to observe what it's doing. In this case, one English description is as follows. *Repeatedly: ( Get three values. If they're all three zeros, stop. If any are non-positive, complain and continue. Else if the three cannot form the sides of a triangle, complain and continue. Otherwise, classify the triangle. )*

Comment: Ok, thanks I've done that. By additional code do you mean your comment? Would you be able to open a chat so I can send you my changes to the while loop?

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69 - I mean the *EDIT* in the answer above. If the non-termination problem has been solved, and have a new problem, you can open a new question.

Comment: Oh sorry just noticed the edit, will read now. It wasn't only a non-termination problem, but I'll check out this code. Thanks!

Comment: this resolves the termination issue but it does not resolve the issue that it accepts one or two zeros and any other number

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69 - You're right, there was still a problem. The boolean expression in the outermost loop and conditional needs to check for *any* nonzero values, with a logical OR rather than a logical AND. I've edited the code above, and put a working copy with sample input at http://ideone.com/4ydryx .

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your code is not terminating is due to nesting your while loops. Although you have included a break statement in the line:

```
if (side1==0&&side2==0&&side3==0)//checks if the user entered 3 zeros to break the loop and terminate the program
    {
      break;
    }
```

You will not exit the outer loops. To fix this, I would suggest reducing the number of loops in your code and checking for valid input in a combined if-statement. That is, instead of placing two nested while loops in your code, you can check for valid input with a single if-statement such as:

```
if((side1==0&&side2==0&&side3==0) || (side1<0||side2<0||side3<0))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: While the nested while loops are an unnecessary complication, they are not the reason the code is not terminating. Combining the error conditions into a single if statement is reasonable if the same error message is desired, but also does not address the problem of non-termination.

Comment: @ZakDaniels99 This definitely helps however, it doesn't remove the fact that it allows inputs like 0, 0, 1 or 0, -1, 2... When I look at it it seems it should only accept zero if it is entered all 3 times. Also values like 3, 7, 1 are now accepted but that cannot make a triangle